# `mysql_real_escape_string()` returns empty MySql Fields

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML contact form in which the user is allowed to write whatever he wants in the `message` input field. This form is being posted using AJAX and being processed in the below PHP.

My problem is that i get an empty row in the MySql Table.

I am simply wondering why `$message = $_POST['message'];` returns the proper value, when `$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);` returns **empty string!!**

**What am I missing here??**

```
  //posted data   
  $firstName  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
  $lastName   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
  $name       = $firstName. ' ' .$lastName ;
  $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $phone      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
  $subject    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
  $hear       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hear']);
  $message    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);


  $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)


  // Check if is Duplicates
  $query_usercheck = " select * from `test` where Name='$name' and Email='$email' and Phone='$phone' and Subject='$subject' and Message='$message' "; //matching all fields
  $usercheck = mysql_query($query_usercheck) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_usercheck = mysql_fetch_assoc($usercheck);
  $totalRows_usercheck = mysql_num_rows($usercheck);

  if ( $totalRows_usercheck > 0 ) {
        $duplicate = 'Yes';
  } else {
        $duplicate = 'No';
        //adding application data to MySql database
        $add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`Date`, `Day`, `Time`, `Name`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Subject`, `From`, `Message`)
        VALUES ('$date','$day','$time','$name','$email','$phone','$subject','$hear','$message')");
  }

// close mysql
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: it probably needs a connection for it, it can happen and place your connection first. Edit: Yeah, I said that ;-)

Comment: whe I use `$message = $_POST['message']` everything goes fine and all strings in my MySql table are filled in

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you connect to the database after you do `mysql_real_escape_string`. Please move your connecting to the database before escaping your variables.

Even better, get rid of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions (there are even gone in PHP7)! Use mysqli or even better: use [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) with prepared statements as even [`mysql_real_escape_string` is not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string).

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string` **requires an active database connection** to do its job. You have not established a connection at the point of calling it.